# Parsing a JSON document in an HTTP response-Arduino (Unexpected response: HTTP/1.1 301 moved permanently error)

Tags: json, http, arduino, httprequest, ethernet

I'm using Arduino's ethernet shield with Arduino mega to parse a JSON document in a HTTP response to read some values in the JSON file.

The JSON address is: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot.

---

I'm getting this error message:

**Connecting...
Connected!
Unexpected response: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently**

Is is that the the Arduino library doesn't have SSL capability, so it can't connect to a secure server? If it is, then I would need your help to resolve this issue.
Or perhaps I need to use another port that's related to https?

---

Here is my code:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;

  // Initialize Ethernet library
  byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
  if (!Ethernet.begin(mac)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to configure Ethernet"));
    return;
  }
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(F("Connecting..."));

  // Connect to HTTP server
  EthernetClient client;
  client.setTimeout(10000);
  if (!client.connect("api.coinbase.com", 80)) {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
    return;
  }

  Serial.println(F("Connected!"));

  // Send HTTP request
  client.println(F("GET /v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot/response.json HTTP/1.0"));
  client.println(F("Host: api.coinbase.com"));
  client.println(F("Connection: close"));
  if (client.println() == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to send request"));
    return;
  }

  // Check HTTP status
  char status[32] = {0};
  client.readBytesUntil('\r', status, sizeof(status));
  // It should be "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" or "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  if (strcmp(status + 9, "200 OK") != 0) {
    Serial.print(F("Unexpected response: "));
    Serial.println(status);
    return;
  }

  // Skip HTTP headers
  char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
  if (!client.find(endOfHeaders)) {
    Serial.println(F("Invalid response"));
    return;

// the rest of the code related to parsing that I didn't paste for the sake the argument.
```

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Have you tried `client.println(F("GET /v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot HTTP/1.0"));` , so without the `response.json` bit?

Comment: for ARM Arduinos there is a https://github.com/OPEnSLab-OSU/SSLClient

Comment: @ocrdu Thanks for your kind response. I tried that and I got the same error message.

Comment: thanks @Juraj, Unfortunately I'm using the Arduino Mega 2560 that is a microcontroller board based on the ATmega2560.

Comment: I tried logging what happens, and yes, the site redirects to the `https` version of the same URL. You will need to make an `https` request instead of a `http` request for this URL.